# Laravel 4 query giving error

Tags: laravel-4

I have this query in laravel which runs perfectly fine when it finds the data in table but give error when it doesn't find the matched data, how can make query to give no error when it doesn't find data in table ?

```
DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM time 
    WHERE p_day = dayname(CURDATE()) 
    AND CURTIME() BETWEEN p_start AND p_end'))[0];
```

Comment: thats because then there is no item in the array returned by `DB::select`. You would have to check its lenght before accessing it using index operator.

Comment: could you please give me example ?

Comment: see my answer, hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats because then there is no item in the array returned by DB::select. You would have to check its lenght before accessing it using index operator

try sth. like that:

```
$results = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM time 
    WHERE p_day = dayname(CURDATE()) 
    AND CURTIME() BETWEEN p_start AND p_end'));

if (!empty($results))  // or: if (count($results) > 0)
{
    // Stuff was returned
    $desiredResult = $results[0];
    // Your hork here
}
else
{
    // what you need to to if nothing is returned (no matches for your query)...
}
```